# Jython or JACL for CORBA naming service groups mapping

Tags: websphere, jndi, jython, corba, jacl

I'm using **IBM WebSphere 7.0**.

I want to map **CORBA naming service groups** `EVERYONE` to `Cos Naming Write` and `Cos Naming Read` roles. How to do that using **Jython** or **JACL**? Please give some clue, code snippet or a link to extensive **Jython** documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not very secure, so I'll assume you're doing this for development or behind a firewall of some kind.  This Jacl snippet should do what you want:

```
# Loop over all role assignments
foreach roleAssignmentExt [$AdminConfig list RoleAssignmentExt] {
  set role [$AdminConfig showAttribute $roleAssignmentExt role]
  set roleName [$AdminConfig showAttribute $role roleName]

  # Look for the interesting roles.
  if {$roleName == "CosNamingWrite" || $roleName == "CosNamingRead"} {
    # Create an assignment of Everyone isn't already assigned.
    set everyoneRoles [$AdminConfig list EveryoneExt $roleAssignmentExt]
    if {[string length $everyoneRoles] == 0} {
      puts "Adding EveryoneExt to $roleAssignmentExt"
      $AdminConfig create EveryoneExt $roleAssignmentExt {}
    }
  }
}
```